# A discrete and faithful higher genus closed surface group representation $\Gamma \to \mathrm{PSL}(2, \mathbb{C})$ with at least one parabolic value?

Tags: lie-groups, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $g \ge 2$ and $\Gamma := \langle a_1, b_1, \ldots, a_g, b_g\ |\ [a_1, b_1] \cdots [a_g, b_g] \rangle$, and let $\rho : \Gamma \to \mathrm{PSL}(2, \mathbb{C})$ denote a representation which is discrete and faithful. Can $\rho(\Gamma)$ contain a parabolic element $\rho(\gamma_0)$?

I know that $\rho(\Gamma)$ cannot contain a parabolic element if one replaces $\mathrm{PSL}(2, \mathbb{C})$ by $\mathrm{PSL}(2, \mathbb{R})$. Furthermore, Claim 2.28 of [GGKW] implies the sequence $\{d_{G/K}(K, \rho(\gamma_0)^n K)\}$ is $O(\log n)$, where $G := \mathrm{PSL}(2, \mathbb{C})$, $K := \mathrm{PSU}(2)$, and $G/K \cong \mathbb{H}^3$ denotes the Riemannian symmetric space of $G$ (which identifies with the upper half space model of hyperbolic $3$-space). So $\rho$ must not be a quasi-isometric embedding (with respect to the word metric on $\Gamma$), which, according to Remark 2.36, equivalently means $\rho(\Gamma) \subset \mathrm{PSL}(2, \mathbb{C})$ is not a convex cocompact subgroup. (The notes by [K] have a proof of the equivalence, in Lemma 2.3.)

I believe one kind of example of a non-convex-cocompact surface group embedding arises as a holonomy representation of the fundamental group of a surface fiber in certain mapping tori; specifically, those mapping-tori $M_\phi$ arising from a pseudo-Anosov homeomorphism $\phi : \Sigma \to \Sigma$ of a higher genus oriented closed surface. It follows from the mapping torus case of the hyperbolization theorem that $M_\phi$ admits a discrete, faithful, and cocompact  representation $\mathrm{hol} : \pi_1(M_\phi) \to \mathrm{PSL}(2, \mathbb{C})$; see [O]. Since $\pi_1(\Sigma)$ is a non-elementary normal subgroup of $\pi_1(M_\phi) \cong \pi_1(\Sigma) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}$, the limit set of $\mathrm{hol}(\pi_1(\Sigma))$ is all of $\partial \mathbb{H}^3 = \widehat{\mathbb{C}}$, but $\mathrm{hol}(\pi_1(\Sigma)) \backslash \mathbb{H}^3$ has infinite volume (as it contains $\mathbb{Z}$-many copies of $\mathrm{hol}(\pi_1(M_\phi)) \backslash \mathbb{H}^3 \approx M_\phi$). This kind of example doesn't directly answer my question however because $\mathrm{hol}(\pi_1(\Sigma))$ is a subgroup of a uniform lattice of $\mathrm{PSL}(2, \mathbb{C})$, and so is purely hyperbolic.

[GGKW] *Guéritaud, François; Guichard, Olivier; Kassel, Fanny; Wienhard, Anna*, [**Anosov representations and proper actions**](https://doi.org/10.2140/gt.2017.21.485), Geom. Topol. 21, No. 1, 485-584 (2017). [ZBL1373.37095](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1373.37095).

[K] Kassel, Fanny; [Convex Cocompact Groups in Real Rank One and Higher](https://lukyanenko.net/conferences/htt2013/Kassel.pdf), Notes for a talk at the GEAR workshop on Higher Teichmüller–Thurston Theory, Northport, Maine, 23–30 June 2013.

[O] *Otal, Jean-Pierre*, The hyperbolization theorem for fibered 3-manifolds. Transl. from the French by Leslie D. Kay, SMF/AMS Texts and Monographs. 7. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). xiv, 126 p. (2001). [ZBL0986.57001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0986.57001).

Comment: 1. Yes, of course. 2. You are reading wrong sources. The first two are irrelevant. The last one is good but it is not designed to serve as an introduction to Kleinian groups.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I appreciate your directness. Do you have a favorite such introduction? (Or collection of favorites?)

Comment: Remark 8.50 of Thurston's unpublished 2002 manuscript *The Geometry and Topology of Three-manifolds* has a picture of a knot complement and a surface being modified so that it wraps around the knot complement: It's clear that a ribbon (annulus of closed curve) sitting inside of a genus 2 immersed surface can wrap along the cusp, and then one can replace the ribbon with an arbitrarily rolled tube (see picture). Then corollary 8.8.6 (b) says with enough rolls this gives a positive answer to my question, which I'll try to answer if I eventually understand this better and nobody else has.

Comment: You can start with "Hyperbolic Manifolds and Kleinian Groups" by Matsuzaki and Taniguchi. Some proofs are sloppy, but you will get a good overall picture. For a collection of of examples I suggest Maskit's "Kleinian groups" (Chapter "A Trip to the Zoo") and Krushkal-Apanasov-Gusevskii "Kleinian groups and uniformization..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to construct such examples. One way is to use a Maskit Combination theorem (for amalgamated free product), amalgamating two single-cusped Fuchsian subgroups along a parabolic subgroup. You can find such constructions in the books B.Maskit "Kleinian groups" or/and Krushkal, Apanasov, Gusevskii "Kleinian groups and uniformization in examples and problems."

A better (in a sense) way is as follows. Start with a genus $g$ Fuchsian group $F$. Let $U^\pm$ denote the disjoint $F$-invariant open disks in $S^2$. Then the space of quasiconformal deformations of $F$ can be parameterized as $T(U^+/F)\times T(U^-/F)$, where $T$ denoted the Teichmuller space. Now, pick a simple essential loop $c$ on $U^+/F$ and let $D_c$ denote the Dehn twist along $c$. Fix $(\tau, \tau)\in T(U^+/F)\times T(U^-/F)$ and consider the sequence of quasifuchsian representations $\rho_n: F\to PSL(2,C)$ corresponding to the sequence of pairs $(\tau, D_c^n\tau)$. One can show that $\rho_n$ subconverges (and even converges) to a representation $\rho: F\to PSL(2,C)$ such that $\rho(c)$ is parabolic. The representation $\rho$ will be necessarily
discrete and faithful. (I am suppressing the "normalization" issue of the representations since they are only defined up to conjugation in  $PSL(2,C)$.) An alternative is to take a sequence parameterizd by $(\tau, \tau_n)$ where each $\tau_n$ is obtained from $\tau$ by fixing all Fenchel-Nielsen parameters except for the length parameter corresponding to $c$, which you set to converge to zero as $n\to\infty$. See for instance Theorem 4.69 and Lemma 4.68 in K.Ohshika's book "Kleinian groups".

More generally, one has the following:

Suppose that $M$ is a compact, oriented, connected, irreducible,  atoroidal 3-dimensional manifold with nonempty boundary such that (for simplicity) the boundary contains no tori. Let $c$ be a compact 1-dimensional submanifold of $\partial M$ such that no two distinct components of $c$ are freely homotopic in $M$. Then there exists a discrete and faithful representation $\rho: \pi_1(M)\to PSL(2,C)$ which sends each component of $c$ to a parabolic element.  This is an application of Thurston's hyperbolization theorem.